# setting an x11vnc password file

Tags: password, vnc

I want to set x11vnc password via puppet/foreman.

Is there any way to make a password file server-side?
I want to be able to put it in foreman plaintext (or pre-obscured one but without installing x11vnc on puppet master) but I don't want it to be plaintext on controllable machines.
All I had googled so far is that it's obscured by some simple pattern and that there's a

> x11vnc --storepassword

command.